# How to boot/install on raspberry pi

Tags: boot, install, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to install on raspberry pi 4. I have 8gb RAM and 128gb micro sd card. I verified the download, used etcher to install on mirco sd card. I insert the micro sd card and turn on the pi and it does not boot. Nothing happens. What do I do?

Comment: If you use etcher on the very same SD card and install raspian, will that card boot the raspberry pi? Doing so would at least eliminate the SD card as the fail point. (perhaps, even more basic, can you boot that same pi with any SD card?) I cannot find the reference at present, but I swear I remember reading something about the size of some SD cards in some versions of the firmware. I have come to eOS from tinkering with a number of pis for things around the house)

Comment: Yes, the sd card works. I’ve used it before. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this same thing!

Raspberry Pi is an ARM device, so you'd need an ARM compatible ISO image. You have two options:

1. Frankenstein it yourself:
   You need the Ubuntu from the rpi-imager burnt onto an sd card, and then you manually add the eOS repos yourself. Here's a link:

https://techviewleo.com/install-pantheon-desktop-environment-on-ubuntu/

2. Pay for it:
   There IS an early access build for raspberry pi from the elementary team, but you have to sign up for a monthly sponsorship of $10+/mo for that. Here's that link:

https://builds.elementary.io/

Best of luck!,
Jake

Comment: Thanks! Whatever I read on elementary OS website about the raspberry pi installation never mention an early access version. Or at least I don’t recall it and that’s why it doesn’t work! I tried the iso on my Mac and it installed elementary from my usb there. I’m going to give your link a try. Sounds straightforward enough. Thank you!